# Apexcharts - set border for specific marker in scatter plot

Tags: scatter-plot, apexcharts

I am trying to set the border for specific markers in a scatter plot chart using Apexcharts.

I am able to set the fillcolor like this:

```
series: [
  {
    name: 'Points',
    data: [
      {
        x: 3.2,
        y: 5.8
      },
      {
        x: 3.8,
        y: 6.04,
        fillColor: '#111'
      },
      {
        x: 4.55,
        y: 6.77
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I cant make it work for borders. I have tried with `strokeColor: '#eee'` but nothing is changed.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Some working example on codepen could help to understand your needs and provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can style markers individually via the [discrete](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/markers/#markerDiscrete) option. Here is an example:

```js
 const options = {
      series: [{
        name: 'Points',
        data: [{
            x: 3.2,
            y: 5.8
          },
          {
            x: 3.8,
            y: 6.04,
          },
          {
            x: 4.55,
            y: 6.77
          }
        ]
      }],
      markers: {
        size: 8,
        discrete: [{
          seriesIndex: 0,
          dataPointIndex: 1,
          fillColor: '#111',
          strokeColor: '#eee',
          size: 8
        }]
      },
      chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
      },
    };
    const chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
    chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
```